# Update a list of row with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a "pause" table, and a `MesPieces` table. When a pieces is put in pause, I insert a row with a timestamp for the `Stop In` time, when this piece is put out of pause, I insert a timestamp for the `Stop Out` time.

When I update the time in the `MesPieces` table, I need to add each time difference for each `MesPieces` id.

```
UPDATE Pause SET stopOut = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM MesPieces
WHERE MesPieces.idMesPieces = Pause.idMesPieces
AND MesPieces.pauseAutomatique = 1
AND stopOut is NULL

UPDATE MesPieces set Statut = 'En cours', 
pauseAutomatique = 0,
tempsPause = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,stopIn,stopOut)
FROM Pause WHERE
Statut = 'Pause'
AND pauseAutomatique = 1
AND Pause.idMesPieces = MesPieces.idMesPieces
```

Here is an exemple of the Pause table

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | idMesPieces |         stopIn          |         stopOut         |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 12 |         123 | 2014-10-07 10:53:09.270 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 13 |         123 | 2014-10-07 11:18:42.797 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 14 |         124 | 2014-10-07 11:18:42.797 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 15 |         125 | 2014-10-07 11:18:42.797 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 16 |         126 | 2014-10-07 11:18:42.797 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 17 |         123 | 2014-10-07 11:21:01.910 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 18 |         124 | 2014-10-07 11:21:01.910 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 19 |         125 | 2014-10-07 11:21:01.910 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 20 |         126 | 2014-10-07 11:21:01.910 | 2014-10-07 11:23:10.140 |
| 21 |         123 | 2014-10-07 11:27:22.837 | 2014-10-07 11:27:38.623 |
| 22 |         124 | 2014-10-07 11:27:22.837 | 2014-10-07 11:27:38.623 |
| 23 |         125 | 2014-10-07 11:27:22.837 | 2014-10-07 11:27:38.623 |
| 24 |         126 | 2014-10-07 11:27:22.837 | 2014-10-07 11:27:38.623 |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

And here is the MesPieces table

```
+-------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+--------+-------------------------+------------+------------------+
| idMesPieces | Poste |  Statut  | Quantitee | TempsUtilise | TempsRestant | idMo  | TempsStd | idUser |       timeOuvert        | tempsPause | pauseAutomatique |
+-------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+--------+-------------------------+------------+------------------+
|         122 | NULL  | Fin      | NULL      |          164 |         -154 | 10111 |       10 |      1 | 2014-10-07 08:31:58.103 |          0 |                0 |
|         123 | NULL  | En cours | NULL      |           34 |          -79 | 10106 |       15 |      1 | 2014-10-07 10:19:06.857 |         30 |                0 |
|         124 | NULL  | En cours | NULL      |            6 |            5 | 10105 |       15 |      1 | 2014-10-07 11:15:25.930 |          0 |                0 |
|         125 | NULL  | En cours | NULL      |            3 |            2 | 10109 |       15 |      1 | 2014-10-07 11:15:26.200 |          5 |                0 |
|         126 | NULL  | En cours | NULL      |            6 |            5 | 10108 |       15 |      1 | 2014-10-07 11:15:26.840 |          0 |                0 |
+-------------+-------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------+----------+--------+-------------------------+------------+------------------+
```

From what I understand, the problem is that in my update, when I add the `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,stopIn,stopOut)` I'm only adding the first match... I don't know how to Add all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but you can join on a query with the group by

```
UPDATE MesPieces 
set 
    Statut = 'En cours', 
    pauseAutomatique = 0,
    tempsPause = Pause.duration
FROM MesPieces 
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        Pause.idMesPieces,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,stopIn,stopOut)) duration
    from Pause, MesPieces
    WHERE
        Statut = 'Pause' AND 
        pauseAutomatique = 1 AND
        Pause.idMesPieces = MesPieces.idMesPieces
    group by
        idMesPieces
) Pause on 
    Pause.idMesPieces = MesPieces.idMesPieces
```

Comment: Thank you, i've made a small change to the code, but it's perfeclty working. Thank you!